# Better understanding Family Sharing (Can I share app from OSX to my iOS device?)

Tags: ios-appstore, mac-appstore, sharing, family-sharing

I'm trying to figure out (for the first time) Family Sharing feature. So far I've added family members and everything seems to work fine except one thing.

I've bought from App Store Tweetbot **for OSX**. Is it possible to share cross-platform applications? I would like to install it on my iPad. Is it possible? Or can I share only between OSX to OSX and iOS to iOS?

Does Tweetbot (or any other app) bought for OSX is something completely different than Tweetbot for iOS? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but one cannot share apps (all apps, not just Tweetbot) cross-platform, for whatever reason. Not with Family Sharing or iCloud. The only way to get it would be to purchase it at full price from the iOS App Store.

Comment: So if I bought that app for Mac, I can only share it with another family member on his / her Mac?

Comment: @slick That's right